# How can i make the bootstrap datepicker never closes?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I use bootstrap datepicker as shown in this html code:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"> 
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
$('.datepicker').datepicker('show');
$(".datepicker").on("changeDate", function(event) {

});
});
</script>

</head>

<body >

<div class="datepicker" data-date=""></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want when i click outside the calendar it will never closes and keep showing on the screen and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$('.datepicker').data('datepicker').hide = function () {};`

to keep open always

**full code**
*js*

```
$(function () {
$('.datepicker').datepicker('show');
$(".datepicker").on("changeDate", function(event) {

});
});
$('.datepicker').data('datepicker').hide = function () {};
```

*html*

```
<body >

<div class="datepicker" data-date=""></div>

</body>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mya2jLca/)